# Included chapters appear on wrong side & page number

Tags: page-numbering

Suppose I want my book to start with Chapter 3 starting on a right-hand page with page number 10.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,extrafontsizes,twoside,openright,final]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\setcounter{page}{9}    
\setcounter{chapter}{2} 

\include{ch3}
\include{ch4}
\include{ch5}

\end{document}
```

(The file `ch3.tex` contains simply `\chapter{Charlie} \lipsum`. Same with `ch4.tex` and `ch5.tex`.)

This results in:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the Chapter 3 begins on page 11, despite my setting the page to 9 immediately before including it. **Q1: What's the problem?**

(**Q2:** Also, Chapter 3 is on a left-handed page, not a right-handed page, despite my using the `openright` option of `memoir`. I'm assuming this is because Adobe Reader always starts pages on the left, whereas a book would open to a right-hand page first. Is this correct?)

Comment: Try with `\cleardoublepage` before `\include{ch3}`.

Comment: Have Adobe learned that the first page in a two sided view is a right hand page? Mostly it just opens it as the first page on the left, thus ruining the view of it.

Comment: An even numbered page is a left-handed page by definition.

Comment: @Johannes_B, how widespread is that convention?

Comment: Everywhere (not sure about RTL typesetting). Pick a magazine from your desk, place it in front of you. The title staring at you has page number one, open it. The back of the title is on the left and has pagenumber two, the right hand page is 3. Or pick any book from your shelve.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Thanks. After sampling a few books, I see that "page 1" always appears on the right, but may be preceded by several "page i, ii, iii" pages (for which "page i" always starts on the right).

Answer (score 3):

Set up Adobe Acrobat Reader as follows:

[image]

By default, the entry “Show Cover Page in Two Page View” is not checked.

Then you have the following view:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Q1: insert a `\cleardoublepage` after `\tableofcontents`.  This will eject the current page before it will procede to go on in your document.

```
\documentclass[12pt,extrafontsizes,twoside,openright,final]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage{}
\setcounter{page}{9}    
\setcounter{chapter}{2} 

\include{ch3}
\include{ch4}
\include{ch5}

\end{document}
```

Q2: Assuming your pagestyle was set up, to print page numbers on the outer margin, and that right pages have odd page numbers, everything is correct.  Open your PDF file with the standard mac preview tool and press CMD-3, you will see the correct page order with right pages on the right hand side.

Comment: Thanks @Jan. Regarding Q2, Mac Preview unfortunately can't be trusted to always display odd pages on the right; do `\setcounter{page}{10}` for an example. In the CMD-3 ("two page" view), Preview appears to simply display the first page on its own, and subsequent pages paired up, with no regard to the page numbers.